# Word to use when you don't understand a sport or video-game language

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to find this word for ages. It's on the tip of my tongue, but I can't find it. Here's a scenario:

> - Guy 1: Did you see that curve ball by that baseball player?
> - Guy 2: Yeah that was really well done!
> - Guy 3: I don’t understand a thing Guy 1 and 2 are saying. They are using so much _____

The blank part is a word that I can't remember.

Answer (score 13):

The word typically used for this is **jargon**:

> Special words or expressions that are used by a particular profession or group and are difficult for others to understand.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jargon)</sub>

For example:

- [Video Game Vocabulary, Jargon, and Slang - Lee Laughead's](http://www.leelaughead.com/video-game-vocabulary-jargon-and-slang/)
- [The comprehensive guide to sports jargon | FOX Sports](https://www.foxsports.com/buzzer/gallery/sports-jargon-comprehensive-guide-high-ceiling-coach-clutch-gene-beanball-hat-trick-052417)

Answer (score 2):

One word for this is ***lingo***

Defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lingo) as:

> b : the special vocabulary of a particular field of interest *The book has a lot of computer lingo.*

Guy 3: They are using so much ***lingo*** that can't understand a word they're saying.

And just for grins, since your question used Baseball as an example, here's a site on [Baseball Slang and Lingo](http://www.lootmeister.com/mlb/slang.php)

Answer (score 0):

While *jargon* and *lingo* are general terms for this idea, a more domain-specific term for this is ***sportsing***.   Anecdotally, I have heard it mostly used by peers who are sports-averse.

[image: example usage from the vectorbelly webcomic]